# RecyclerView not showing data from JSON Array after parsing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I'm trying to get a JSON array using Android Volley but my RecyclerView not showing data. the recyclerView is empty. I have checked my URL there is no problem.

BackgroundTask.java

```
    public class BackgroundTask {

    Context context;
    String jsonURL = "my url";
    ArrayList<Contact> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public BackgroundTask(Context ctx){

        this.context = ctx;
    }

    public ArrayList<Contact> getList(){

        final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, jsonURL, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        int count = 0;
                        while (count > response.length()){
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                                Contact contact = new Contact(jsonObject.getString("Name"),jsonObject.getString("Email"));
                                arrayList.add(contact);
                                count++;

                            } catch (JSONException e) {

                                Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }
        );
        Singletone.getSingletone(context).addToRequest(jsonArrayRequest);
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

MySingletone.java

```
    public class Singletone {

    private static Singletone singletone;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private static Context context;

    private Singletone(Context ctx){
        context = ctx.getApplicationContext();
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){

        if(requestQueue == null){
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public static synchronized Singletone getSingletone(Context ctx){

        if(singletone == null){
            singletone = new Singletone(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return singletone;
    }

    public<T> void addToRequest(Request<T> request){

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

}
```

RecyclerAdapter.java

```
    public class RecycleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Contact> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    public RecycleAdapter(ArrayList<Contact> array){

        this.arrayList = array;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        MyViewHolder myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return  myViewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.Name.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName().toString());
        holder.Email.setText((arrayList.get(position).getEmail().toString()));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView Name, Email;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
            Email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is asynchronous. You cant just return the `ArrayList` from `getList` method. You have to populate the `RecyclerView` inside the callback method `onResponse` by calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Also your `while` loop never runs because `count` is never greater than `response.length()`;

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if(response != null && response.length() > 0){
        for (int count = 0; count < response.length(); count++ ) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                Contact contact = new Contact(jsonObject.getString("Name"), jsonObject.getString("Email"));
                arrayList.add(contact);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: how to call adpter.notifyDataSetChanged inside the onResponse()?

Comment: how to call adpter.notifyDataSetChanged inside the onResponse() ? my adapter object inside another activity and i'm calling BackgroundTask fromthat activity. thank you.

Comment: Make the adapter object global.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
int count = 0;
while (count > response.length()){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
        Contact contact = new Contact(jsonObject.getString("Name"),jsonObject.getString("Email"));
        arrayList.add(contact);
        count++;

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

to

```
 for(int count=0;count<response.length();count++){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
        Contact contact = new Contact(jsonObject.getString("Name"),jsonObject.getString("Email"));
        arrayList.add(contact);

    } catch (JSONException e) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @SabirHossain you're welcome...don't forget to upvote or accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after updating `arrayList`